# How do I recover a file only saved to my local repo that was deleted during Git revert?

Tags: git

I reverted a Git commit using `git revert` but doing so deleted crucial files that were only saved to my local repo. How can I recover those files?

Comment: `git revert` does not *delete* **anything**. Instead, it *adds a new commit*. The existing commits remain intact. Note, however, that your working tree may contain files that were never committed (are not in any commit); if you delete one of these files, Git can't get it back because Git never had it. (`git revert` won't normally clobber one of these files, though.)

Comment: @torek That's a bit misleading. If you revert a commit which just created some files then those files will be deleted from your working tree.

Comment: @CalumHalpin: true, I meant to say doesn't delete anything *from the repository* (which is why I added the comment about working tree files that were never committed). It's important to realize that working tree files aren't in the repository.

Comment: thank you all. this is resolved. I used git reflog to view prior commits and then git revert to return to that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) to restore the files as they were before your reversion:

```
git restore --source=<id-of-revert-commit>^ -- <path-to-file> <path-to-other-file>...
```